# How to detect when video has stopped playing and perform action thereafter(Android)

Tags: android, video, imageview, android-videoview

In my program when user clicks on imagepreview video starts running.Video is played in same actvity in which images are.When video is played images are made invisible.I want that when video stop it should disappear and images should be visible.I tried using isPlaying() method but doesn't work out as expected.If I put isPlaying() method inside onClick() then the action inside isPlaying() is performed even before the video is started and if i place it ouside setOnClickListener() then this method doesn't execute when video is stopped.Plzz help me with code

```
 imgPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //clicking on first imageView

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imgPreview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    videoPreview2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 


                    videoPreview2.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());

                    videoPreview2.start();


                }

 });


if(videoPreview2.isPlaying()==false){
                imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgPreview2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                videoPreview2.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried videoview's setcompletion listener. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29).

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //make image visible here
}
});
```

Comment: - MediaPlayer cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) in the type VideoView is not applicable for the arguments (new 
  OnCompletionListener(){})

Comment: you dont have new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(). please copy the code instead of typing